# Blazer gem: Scheduled rake tasks not working automatically but work fine when invoked from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduled-tasks, whenever

I have set up a couple of rake tasks to run automatically with the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem . The tasks involve running a background Job, performing a database Blazer check and sending failing checks emails.

The last two are provided by the [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#checks-optional) gem.

This is my `schedule.rb` file:

```
set :environment, "development"

every 1.minutes do
  rake "health_check:perform"
end

every 1.minutes do
  rake 'blazer:run_checks'
end

every 2.minutes do
  rake "blazer:send_failing_checks"
end
```

The "health_check:perform" rake task always performs as expected, and I can see the Job being run in my server log every minute.

The other two, however, don't seem to be executing at all.

I can tell `blazer:run_checks` is not executing because when a Blazer check is run either manually or automatically, the `blazer_checks` table `last_run_at` column value is updated with the timestamp when the last check was run. Also, I can see the update DB transaction in my server log when that happens.

On the other hand "blazer:send_failing_checks" is not working either because well, no emails are ever delivered.

However, if I manually invoke the task from my console via `rake "blazer:run_checks"` or `rake "blazer:send_failing_checks"` they perform normally (`blazer_checks` table is updated and failing check emails are delivered).

I can't spot any error messages in my server log, altough I believe by default rake tasks are set to run in `silent` mode? Since running `whenever -l` to list my `crontab` file returns something like:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/code/myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake health_check:perform --silent'

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/code/myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake blazer:run_checks --silent'

0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/code/myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake blazer:send_failing_checks --silent'
```

Any ideas? How can I debug this?

Comment: did you try specifying schedule with rake task as given in doc. `rake blazer:run_checks SCHEDULE="5 minutes"` it should look like this in cron `*/5 * * * * rake blazer:run_checks SCHEDULE="5 minutes"`

Comment: I tried that. It seems like it is actually performing the checks, but the emails are not delivered until I visit the endpoint where the check query is `/blazer/queries/1-healthcheck` . I wonder if it could be some sort of authentication problem, but  I don't get any errors in the server log.

Comment: did you try logging your cron jobs?  check here http://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs

Comment: Thanks! I configured a log output and sure enough it seems that it is actually delivering 
 emails but I can't see it because I have set up `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener` in my `development.rb` file but it can't find a browser to display the sent email as in the log it says `no method available for opening 'file:////home/user/app/tmp/letter_opener/1674230167_9189203_de0207e/rich.html'` and `Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.`

Comment: check if this helps to set browser environment variable https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-browser-environment-variable-on-linux